# I need to specify the filename when running a local report creating a pdf. It currently uses the aspx page name

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I generate reports using this code which download to the user download folder. At present they all have the same name with a number added along with the aspx extension.  I need to create a specific name for each file along with the pdf extension.

```
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
viewer.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new    PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; ffilename=Recipe." + extension);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file    
Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
```

I am expecting to get a file name that I specify with the pdf extension placed in the user download folder.

Comment: Please specify the issue. Do you need to figure out a way to name the files or does the code not work? If the latter, please provide more details

Comment: The code works, I need to name the file.

Comment: So you want a "save to" window client-side, basically?

Comment: No I simply want it to go to the downloads folder, which it did.  I just need to specify a name.pdf when when the user runs it.

Comment: you have "ffilename", and that is incorrect. You need "filename" in your code. Also, you don't show where you setup the variable extension. So, if you fox the ffilename bug, then your file will always be called receipe.pdf. You could add a date or some such, but your posted code has bugs. fix that bug, and then you should get the correct file name.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much, sometimes the eyes just don't catch things!